# Как удалить группу AD через powershell без подтверждения

Tags: powershell

Win10Pro все модули AD подгружены и работают исправно
При ручном подтверждении без Confirm $false удаляет без ошибок.
SamAccountName удаляемой группы Distribution_Mail_Group_16458

Попытка №1:

```
Get-ADGroup Distribution_Mail_Group_16458 | Remove-ADGroup -Confirm $false
```

Ошибка:
*Remove-ADGroup : Не удается привязать параметр "Identity". Не удается преобразовать значение "False" в тип "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup". Ошибка: "Недопустимое приведение "System.Boolean" к "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup"."*

Попытка №2:

```
Remove-ADGroup Distribution_Mail_Group_16458 -Confirm $false
```

Ошибка:
*Remove-ADGroup : Не удается найти позиционный параметр, принимающий аргумент "False".*

Попытка №3:

```
Remove-ADGroup Distribution_Mail_Group_16458 -Confirm $false
```

Ошибка:
*Remove-ADGroup : Не удается найти позиционный параметр, принимающий аргумент "False".*

Answer (score 1):

Нужно так:

```
Remove-ADGroup Distribution_Mail_Group_16458 -Confirm:$false
```

т.е. между confirm и $false должно стоять двоеточие